# read data from database with architect mvc in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want read data from database in codeigniter and with MVC architecture. 
This is my controller layer:

```
class select_ctrl extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
$this -> load -> view('select_view');
$this -> load -> model('select_model');
$this -> select_model -> example();
}
}
```

this is my model layer :

```
class select_model extends CI_Model{
function example(){
$this -> load ->view('select_view');
$query = $this->db->get_where('exam', array('id' => '1'), 4, 1);
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
$name  = $row->name;
$this -> select_view -> display($name);
}
}       
}
```

and this is my view layer :

```
function display ($name){
echo ($name);
}
```

I want read data in model layer and display in view layer. 
But there is this error:

> Cannot redeclare `display()`

please say what is problem this code or say how I should read data from database in model layer and display in view layer with architect mvc ?

Comment: there are too many mistakes in this code. the solution is - work through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual. work through it slowly, step by step, so you really understand it.

Comment: You load the view file twice. First time in the controller and the second time in the model.